# undefined reference while vector of boost::scoped_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, vector

Intel compiler
icpc version 13.0.1 (gcc version 4.4.6 compatibility)

```
#include "boost/scoped_ptr.hpp"
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<boost::scoped_ptr<int> > v;
    v.push_back(boost::scoped_ptr<int> (new int(127)));

    return 0;
}
```

icpc bbb21.cpp

```
/devjuser1/jp/ccjp/avinokur/tmp/icpclHkUcJ.o: In function `main':
bbb21.cpp:(.text+0xfa): undefined reference to `boost::scoped_ptr<int>::scoped_ptr(boost::scoped_ptr<int> const&)'
bbb21.cpp:(.text+0x136): undefined reference to `boost::scoped_ptr<int>::scoped_ptr(boost::scoped_ptr<int> const&)'
bbb21.cpp:(.text+0x195): undefined reference to `boost::scoped_ptr<int>::scoped_ptr(boost::scoped_ptr<int> const&)'
bbb21.cpp:(.text+0x254): undefined reference to `boost::scoped_ptr<int>::scoped_ptr(boost::scoped_ptr<int> const&)'
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The type used with `std::vector::push_back()` is required to be either

- move-inertible (`void std::vector<T>::push_back( T&& value );`) or
- copy-insertible (`void std::vector<T>::push_back( const T& value );`).

See [cppreference.com, std::vector::push_back()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)

[Boost docs (1.53), scoped_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm) suggests that `scoped_ptr` can be constructed from a pointer but not copy- or move-constructed.

It states

> scoped_ptr cannot be used in C++ Standard Library containers. Use [shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) if you need a smart pointer that can.

(Which unfortunatelly makes your question being  "not a real question" or "too localized". ;-))

Answer (score 2):

`boost::scoped_ptr` is not copyable while STL container needs elements to be copy constructable.

My advice is to use below steatment isntead:

```
std::vector<int> v;
```

Or you could use boost::shared_ptr instead:

```
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<int> > v;
```

Comment: @Alex, please, do not write your thanks in the comments, use accept button instead.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot copy a scoped_ptr, as the error says, the copy constructor for scoped_ptr is not available. you could use `shared_ptr` instead, which provides almost the same functionality, but would solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have modern implementation that implemented move semantics in STL, use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int> >`. That is the closest equivalent to scoped_ptr.